# ASP.NET MVC beginform for complex property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with binding models in mvc 5. 
For example, I have 2 models:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
     public string FirstProperty {get;set;}
     public string SecondProperty {get;set;}
}
```

and another

```
public class SecondViewModel
{
     public string SimpleProperty{get;set;}
     public FirstViewModel ComplexProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I have a strongly typed view with SecondViewModel model class. And in this View I want to have a form for FirstViewModel, witch will be post this to controller.
It must be something like this:

View

```
@model SecondViewModel

@html.EditorFor(x => x.SimpleProperty)
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstViewModel) // I have a custom editor in EditorTemplates folder
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

And controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(FirstViewModel model)
    {
    }
}
```

But if I do it in this way the FirstViewModel properties are always empty strings. Thanks for advice

Comment: try using a partial page instead of EditorFor(). This worked for me.

Comment: you shou include your FirstViewModel  inside your view

Comment: I assume you mean `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ComplexProperty)`. You need to use `public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Prefix = "ComplexProperty")]FirstViewModel model)` to 'strip' the prefix from binding.